# cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method Dagger/MissingBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-mvp

Unable to inject presenter to Activity

**BookDashboard -> Activity**

```
class BookDashboard : AppCompatActivity(),BookDashboardContract.MvpView{

    @Inject
    lateinit var presenter: BookDashboardContract.Presenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        presenter.fetchedBooks() 
        // if I pass no parameter to BookPresenter than UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property presenter has not been initialized
    }

    override fun displayBooks() {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Books Displayed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun showProgress() {}
    override fun hideProgress() {}
}
```

**BookDashboardContract**

```
interface BookDashboardContract {

    interface MvpView{
        fun displayBooks()
        fun showProgress()
        fun hideProgress()
    }

    interface Presenter{
        fun fetchedBooks()
    }
}
```

**BookDashboardPresenter**
If I pass no parameter to below constructor app will run but still presenter is not injected
and crashed at presenter.fetchBooks() in **BookDashboard** -> `Activity` __ See comments in that code

```
class BookDashboardPresenter @Inject constructor(val viewContract:BookDashboardContract.MvpView) : BookDashboardContract.Presenter{

    val bookInteractor = BookInteractor(this)

    override fun fetchedBooks() {
        bookInteractor.fetchDataFromServer()
        viewContract.displayBooks()
    }
}
```

**ActivityBuilder**

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {BookDashboardModule.class})
    @ActivityScope
    public abstract BookDashboard bindBookDashboard();
}
```

**BookDashboardModule**

```
@Module
abstract class BookDashboardModule {

    @Binds
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun presenter(presenter: BookDashboardPresenter): BookDashboardContract.Presenter
}
```

> Second approach I used. But still presenter isn't injected

```
 @Module
 class BookDashboardModule(val mvpView: BookDashboardContract.MvpView) {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    fun providesCategoryView(): BookDashboardContract.MvpView {
        return this.mvpView
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    fun provideBookPresenter(): BookDashboardPresenter {
        return BookDashboardPresenter(mvpView)
    }
}
```

> @Subcomponent.Factory method is missing parameters for required modules or subcomp

```
@Module(subcomponents = ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard.BookDashboardSubcomponent.class)
public abstract class ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard {
  private ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard() {}

  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ClassKey(BookDashboard.class)
  abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<?> bindAndroidInjectorFactory(
      BookDashboardSubcomponent.Factory builder);

  @Subcomponent(modules = BookDashboardModule.class)
  @ActivityScope
  public interface BookDashboardSubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<BookDashboard> {
    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory extends AndroidInjector.Factory<BookDashboard> {}
  }
}
```

**Edit**

As Onik comment I have replace AppCompatActivity with DaggerAppCompatActivity but still unable to inject presenter

**MvpView cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotate**

```
/Users/geek/StudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/quiz/mania/trivia/mcq/question/di/AppComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.contract.BookDashboardContract.MvpView cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.App> {
                ^
      quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.contract.BookDashboardContract.MvpView is injected at
          quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.presenter.BookDashboardPresenter(viewContract)
      quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.presenter.BookDashboardPresenter is injected at
          quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.di.BookDashboardModule.presenter(presenter)
      quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.contract.BookDashboardContract.Presenter is injected at
          quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.BookDashboard.presenter
      quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.BookDashboard is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T) [quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.di.AppComponent → quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.di.ActivityBuilder_BindBookDashboard.BookDashboardSubcomponent]
```

**AppComponent**

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidInjectionModule::class, // why it is necessary to use this class for injecting purpose
        AppModule::class,
        ActivityBuilder::class
    ]
)
@Singleton
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        fun addContext(@BindsInstance context: Context): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

**App.kt**

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().addContext(this).build()
    }
}
```

Comment: You must create Dagger component by manually initialising the Dagger module, say in the `Activity`'s `onCreate()`.

Comment: @Onik you are right I changed AppCompatActivity with DaggerAppCompatActivity

Comment: Now new error is BookDashboardContract.MvpView cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated meth

Comment: In which class does the error occur?

Comment: When I try to run this applicaiton . This error shows  in Build output in class AppComponent.

Comment: @Onik see edit plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some mess with the dependency graph. Please change your code like below and try again:

```
@Module
 class BookDashboardModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    fun provideBookPresenter(view: BookDashboard): BookDashboardContract.Presenter = BookDashboardPresenter(view)
}
```

////////

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {BookDashboardModule.class})
    @ActivityScope
    abstract fun bind(): BookDashboard
}
```

/////////

```
class BookDashboardPresenter @Inject constructor(val view: BookDashboardContract.MvpView) : BookDashboardContract.Presenter{

    val bookInteractor = BookInteractor(this)

    override fun fetchedBooks() {
        bookInteractor.fetchDataFromServer()
        view.displayBooks()
    }
}
```

Comment: question/di/BookDashboardModule.java:12: error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type
    public abstract quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.booksmvp.contract.BookDashboardContract.Presenter presenter(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()

Comment: AppComponent.java:8: error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this interface because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<quiz.mania.trivia.mcq.question.App> {

Comment: Did you add your ActivityBuilder to AppModule which is added in AppComponent?

Comment: I have added AppComponent and App in my question . See edit section

Comment: Convert your module Binds to Provides. Updated my answer with that check.

Comment: @0xAiHn your solutions works can you tell me why you pass BookDashboard instead of MvpView interface and what's the purpose of annotation ActivityScope

Comment: @XarEAhmer Because we are binding the BookDashboard through ActivityBuilder also ActivityScope is your stuffs i just make the dependency graph workable nothing with activityscope. However, if the solution works do upvote so that others can be helpful from this kind of issue as well.